# What is the use of Glimpse in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I've heard about Glimpse which can be used to see the time taken for each ajax call. I'm wondering if it will be worth of adding Glimpse in my asp.net project.
What is the benefit of using Glimpse in asp.net project?

Comment: It's for debugging and performance tracing purposes

Comment: How can i implement glimpse in my asp.net project?

Comment: follow following link - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IfYoureNotUsingGlimpseWithASPNETForDebuggingAndProfilingYoureMissingOut.aspx

Comment: Can't you just google that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glimpse is a web debugging and diagnostics tool used to gain a better understanding of whats happening inside of your ASP.NET 4.0 application

As you hover over each segment, it pops up with lots of details about the HTTP request, AJAX requests, deep inspection database interactions, and lots more.

You will get detailed answer on following link

[If you're not using Glimpse with ASP.NET for debugging and profiling, you're missing out](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IfYoureNotUsingGlimpseWithASPNETForDebuggingAndProfilingYoureMissingOut.aspx)

Comment: dead project ? alternatives ?